# forward engineer with mysql workbench cannot create the schema

Tags: mysql-workbench

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema motivian
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema motivian
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `motivian` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `motivian` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `motivian`.`user`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `motivian`.`user` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `motivian`.`user` (
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`));


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `motivian`.`calculation`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `motivian`.`calculation` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `motivian`.`calculation` (
  `category_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `calc` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` INT NULL,
  `date_created` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_id`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `motivian`.`user` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

This is auto generated with mysql workbench but the constraint could not be applied. I tried  like this:

CONSTRAINT `user_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`user_id)
        REFERENCES`motivian`.`user`(`user_id)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

but also don't work.....
This is the error:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
    REFERENCES `motivian`.`user` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO A' at line 8
SQL Code:
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `motivian`.`calculation` (
          `category_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `calc` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
          `user_id` INT NULL,
          `date_created` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
          PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`),
          CONSTRAINT `user_id`
            FOREIGN KEY ()
            REFERENCES `motivian`.`user` ()
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

SQL script execution finished: statements: 8 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Answer (score 0):

Your FK definition is incomplete. Youd did not specify any column. Select your foreign key in the table editor and specify column pairs in the list right to it:

[image]